# No module named 'channels'

Tags: django, channel

I am trying to install channels, following their tutorial([channels tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html)) but when I try to run the server I get the error: No module named 'channels'.

I have tried reinstalling it, moving the app to the top of the list of "INSTALLED_APPS" but it still does not work.

I have installed python 3.7 and django 2.1.3

Comment: Did you ever use `pip install channels`?

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to reinstall the `python` Or `django`. You just forgot to install `channels`. Follow [Channel 2.1.7 installation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Try `python -m pip install -U channels`
this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was it conflicted with another library, probably whitenoise. I created a new clear env and it works fine now.

Comment: Channel is an external package of `python`. So, as per your answer you must installed `channels` library in past.

Comment: How did you find the conflicting library and resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have also getting this issue:

you need to run python -m pip install -U channels. This might solve the issue.

Comment: Duplicate of existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069762/5320906